# Multiple integral involving exponential and trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

By using the generating function for Bessel functions I have discovered the following identity:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int\limits_{[0,2 \pi] \times [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2} ]^2}
e^{\imath x \sum\limits_{j=1}^3\left( \cos(2 \phi_j) + \cos(4 \phi_j) + \cos(2 \phi_j + 4 \phi_{(j+1)\%3})\right)}
\prod\limits_{j=1}^3 d \phi_j
=\\
&&
2 \pi^3 
\sum\limits_{(n_j)_{j=4}^9 \in Z^6}
 \imath^{-\sum\limits_{j=4}^6 n_j}
\prod\limits_{p=1}^3 J_{n_{p+6}+2(n_{p+3}+n_{f(p-1)+6})}(x)
\cdot
\prod\limits_{p=4}^9 J_{n_p}(x) 
\end{eqnarray}
where $J_n(x)$ are Bessel functions and $f(p)=p \cdot 1_{p\neq 0} + 3 \cdot 1_{p=0}$.
Is it possible to find a closed form expression for the infinite sum on the right hand side?

Comment: Possible typo in the subscript within the third cosine in the LHS (I suspect %3 isn't intended).

Comment: No, I put the modulo three (%3) on purpose. Bear in mind there are only three integration variables $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$. So if there was no modulo three in that cosine at $j=3$ we would have had a $\phi_4$ which does not exist. By the way I tested the formula using Mathematica and it is correct. Interestingly enough the sum on the right hand side converges quite fast. For $\left|x\right| < 1$ it amounts to cut off that sum at $\pm 3$ and the remaining terms do not contribute anything meaningful.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that % was used like that. By the way, you might find this paper on [multivariable Bessel functions](https://www.dmi.unict.it/ojs/index.php/lematematiche/article/download/376/353) of interest. I'm not certain it gives anything truly 'new' but it provides a nice language for the kind of integral considered here. (Plus, new keywords for literature review).

Comment: Thanks for that paper! this is exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to develop a method to compute integrals of the following kind:  \begin{equation} \int\limits_{[0,2 \pi]^3}e^{\imath \sum\limits_{n_1,n_2,n_3} x_{n_1,n_2,n_3} \cos( n_1 \phi_1 + n_2 \phi_2 + n_3 \phi_3)} \prod\limits_{j=1}^3 d \phi_j\end{equation} It is clear that this integral is somehow related to Bessel functions. The paper you quoted provides tools to evaluate such an integral.